# Rails sqlite3 deploy problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to deploy a small rails app using sqlite3, but I keep getting the following exception: SQLite3::SQLException: unable to open database file. Permissions have been set to:

-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data root 208896 Mar  2 11:26 joboversigt.db

I can read (select) from the database with no problem, put writing isn't working

Comment: Can you show us the setup for the sqlite3 DB in database.yml ? Can you show us the path of the file for the production environment?

Comment: I used this:

adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/joboversigt.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

tried:

adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/joboversigt.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

- as well, the database is located in /srv/www/example.dk/db/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but make sure that the directory containing the database is writable as well.